Nominatim location searching not working on react native project
Earlier in my react native expo project, nominatim search query was working fine. But it doesn't return any location now. Below is the function doing the handleSearch.Thanks in advanced.
const handleSearch = async () => {
    if (!searchQuery) {
      Alert.alert("Error", "Please enter a location to search.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search`, {
        params: {
          q: searchQuery,
          format: 'json',
          addressdetails: 1,
          limit: 1,
        }
      });

      if (response.data.length > 0) {
        const location = response.data[0];
        const latitude = parseFloat(location.lat);
        const longitude = parseFloat(location.lon);

        setMarker({ latitude, longitude });
        setRegion({
          latitude,
          longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        });
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Error", "Location not found.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Error", "Failed to search location.");
    }
  };


Check the usage policy: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/
Check the HTTP request and response headers.
